# Operator/Matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, inequality, operator-theory

Let $A,B$ be  non-negative matrices, such that $0\leq B\leq 1$.

Is it true that $BAB\leq A$? (meant in the quadratic form sense)

$A,B$ do not need to commute in general.

Comment: Could $A = I_2, B = J_2$ be a counter example?

Comment: Sorry, what again is $J_2$?

Comment: All one matrix $[1 1; 1 1]$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones)

Comment: One of its eigenvalues is $2$, thus $B\leq 1$ does not hold.

Comment: Ok, inequality in matrices has some different interpretations. It could have been pointwise inequality in this case.

Comment: I can prove it for base elements. WLOG choose an eigenbase of $B$. Then, $\langle \phi_i, BAB\phi_i\rangle = \lambda_i^2 \langle\phi_i, A\phi_i\rangle \leq \langle\phi_i, A\phi_i\rangle.$

Comment: Does it extend to general vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong.

Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\frac{1}{2} J_2$.